# How to get the collapsed Kendo TreeList row?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-treelist

I have a Kendo TreeList and the collapse event bound to an `onCollapse()` method.

I've tried to get the collapsed row with `e.source` but that's **undefined**.

In methods bound to dragstart, drop and some other events,  `e.source` is the row,   but not in the collapse event.

How can I get the row intended to collapse?

Here is the code:

```
onCollapse: function (e) {
    console.log(e.source) //undefined
    var row = **?** ;    
    var dataItem = treeList.dataItem(row);
    if (dataItem.Level == 0) { //my dataitems have levels
        console.log("Prevent collapsing the ParentRow of all rows");
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

----------- **solved** (see answer) --------
 solution: *e.model*

```
onCollapse: function (e) {
        if (e.model.Level == 0) {
            console.log("Prevent collapsing the ParentRow of all rows");
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked out this option https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treelist/api - in toggleGroup  you have how to collapse or expand a row.

Comment: thanks, and how can I know the index?

Comment: can you share more code on how do you select your row. and were you get your "undefined" so it will be easier to help.

Comment: sure, I added code to my question. The selection is done by the kendo lib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried something, not sure how your data looks, but take a look:

```
<script>
    $("#treeList").kendoTreeList({
      columns: [
        { field: "Name" },
        { field: "Position" }
      ],
      dataSource: [
        { id: 1, Name: "Daryl Sweeney", Position: "CEO", parentId: null, expanded: true },
        { id: 2, Name: "Guy Wooten", Position: "Chief Technical Officer", parentId: 1 }
      ],
      collapse: function(e) {
        console.log("collapse", e.model);
        console.log("collapse", e.model.Name); //will get Daryl Sweeney
      }
    });
</script>
```

So in this case it will write the name of the item that collapses.

Here also a Dojo for testing: https://dojo.telerik.com/isiBaVEt

Cheers